# Max length of an array after reading a CSV (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm currently reading in a CSV file that has thousands of items. After checking the Google Chrome console, it's producing arrays that hold the values in sets of 100. Is there a way to get around this? I'm going to be uploading several documents into D3 and based on a selection, I'm going to merge the CSV files of the teams that are selected by the user and perform various functions on said selection. Will the sets of 100 affect subsequent applications of the data?

Here is a link to the [CSV files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1STkAK-zwm9H_qtAxlZNyE381pyvMK35O).

And my test code is here.

```
d3.csv("data/ArsenalDictionary.csv", function(error1, data1) {
    console.log(data1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a display in the console thing - the array itself isn't segmented like that. It's done for convenience (I think) so you can inspect different parts of a large array more easily.

You can see it in action by opening the console and doing:

```
Array(1000).fill(0)
```

and then you can expand it out and see the `[0 ... 99]`, `[100 ... 199]` etc.